# How do I check values of one column with other values of another column of another sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have two columns in two different sheets. Both sheets have a list of values with title 'Reference No'. Let the two columns be Column J of Sheet1 and Column L of Sheet2. I want to compare each value of the two columns and find those values of Sheet2 which are not there in any row of Sheet1. I want those values to be typed somewhere below in Sheet1 in any column. How do I do that using macros and VBA?

Comment: why does it have to be VBA? What have you tried at this point?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a formula for that and then just filter the results (FALSE or TRUE).

The formula you need is something similar to the following: `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2;A$2:A$8;0))`

In the above formula C2 is the cell you want to check if it exists in the Range A2:A8 (the range on your first sheet) and 0 means you need to match exactly the two. MATCH will return the position in the range that first founds a match if exists. Then with ISNUMBER if MATCH returns a numbered position, you turn that into a true or false answer.

See example below in screenshot:
[image]

**EDIT:** In order to clarify the above answer I will give another screenshot and hope that it is clear enough now.

Imagine the colored areas being in different sheets. Just filter the FALSE and you will get the expected result.

[image]

Comment: You should replace `A2:A8` in the formula with `A$2:A$8`. Otherwise the formula won't work if you drag it down.

Comment: The two columns are in two different sheets and I want to filter out only those values which are not common in the two columns.

Comment: @raemaerne You are right. My bad. I have edited my answer correctly now!

Comment: @PranavM What I proposed above will tell you which of the elements in the second column exist (or not) in the first column. You can do the same for the first to the second column. Then just filter in both sheets those that are FALSE and voila. You can also put that in a macro if you want.

Comment: Thanks @Blenikos. But can you help write a vba macros for it.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow and we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems. You could try the build-in macro recorder in excel and start your macro from there. Just do what you want by hand and leave excel to write most of the code for you. Then just edit on the code what you want on that result and if you stuck anywhere, edit your question, add your code and I will help you with that.